# Pandas datetime column to ordinal

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I'm trying to create a new Pandas dataframe column with ordinal day from a datetime column:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

print df.ix[0:5]
                              date
file                              
gom3_197801.nc 2011-02-16 00:00:00
gom3_197802.nc 2011-02-16 00:00:00
gom3_197803.nc 2011-02-15 00:00:00
gom3_197804.nc 2011-02-17 00:00:00
gom3_197805.nc 2011-11-14 00:00:00

df['date'][0].toordinal()

Out[6]:
734184

df['date'].toordinal()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-dbfd5e8b60f0> in <module>()
----> 1 df['date'].toordinal()

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'toordinal'
```

I guess this is a basic question, but I've struggled reading docs for last 30 minutes.

How can I create an ordinal time column for my dataframe?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use apply:

```
df['date'].apply(lambda x: x.toordinal())
```

Comment: Shortly, `df['date'].apply(datetime.toordinal)`

Answer (score 12):

you can also use `map`:

```
import datetime as dt
df['date'].map(dt.datetime.toordinal)
```

Comment: The timedata is rounded into a integer, For example, I have `2015-12-08 12:13:46.343000` but this is rounded to 735940, how can i get with the decimals?

Answer (score 3):

For completeness:
Apply `pd.Timestamp.toordinal`

```
df['date'].apply(pd.Timestamp.toordinal)
```