# Pandas time series how to get the day of month?

Tags: pandas

There're method "dayofyear","dayofweek"to get the Timestamp's feature.Is there a method to calculate the day ordinal of a quarter or a month?

Comment: The answer looks like it's to a different problem (Pandas datetime column to ordinal: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20576618/pandas-datetime-column-to-ordinal). Is there anything there related to day of month? Ordinal in this case refers to day of year (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.toordinal.html).